# Kendo UI Grid with object ID translation

Tags: json, datasource, kendo-ui, crud, kendo-grid

I'm trying to make a grid with KendoUI with external data via JSON (php+mysql engine) from TABLE A and one of columns of these data, get text labels from another TABLE B.

Example, data are: `idPermission=1`, `user_id=1`, `business_unit_id=1`, `permission=10`

The `user_id=1` I want get from another table (`Users`) their names, `1=John Doe`, `2=Martin Brown`.

I want to see "John Doe" instead id 1 in the visualization of grid, and "Martin Brown" instead id 2. When inline (or popup) editing of the records I've already reached the target, and I've a select box with the names and not the ids!

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost/ajax/";
        var dataTable = "UsersPermissions"; 

        // This is the datasource of the grid
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:  {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "table_action.php?op=R&tbl="+dataTable,
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "table_action.php?op=U&tbl="+dataTable,
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "table_action.php?op=D&tbl="+dataTable,
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "table_action.php?op=C&tbl="+dataTable,
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "idPermission",
                    fields: {
                        idPermission: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        user_id: { validation: { required: true } },
                        business_unit_id: {},
                        permission: { validation: { required: true } },
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // This is the datasource of the user_id column
        usersSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:  {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "table_action.php?op=R&tbl=Users",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "idUser",
                    fields: {
                        idUser: {},
                        email: {},
                        password: {},
                        name: {},
                        last_login: {},
                        status: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            sortable: {
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: false
            },
            reorderable: true,
            resizable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                {                    
                    field: "user_id",
                    editor: function (container, options) {     // This is where you can set other control types for the field.                                                                   
                        $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox({
                            dataSource: usersSource,
                            dataValueField: "idUser",
                            dataTextField: "name",                            
                        });
                    },
                    title: "ID Utente"
                },
                { field: "business_unit_id", title: "Business Unit"},
                { field: "permission", title: "Permission"},
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: "230px"}],
            editable: "inline"
        });

    });

</script>
```

How I can make the same thing I've done in editing mode, in view mode?

Comment: can you show your json data?

Answer (score 0):

For achieving that you have to first edit the query of the read operation seeing your sample data it must be like this

```
SELECT  a.idPermission, b.name, a.business_unit_id, a.permission 
FROM TABLE_A AS a 
JOIN TABLE_B(users) AS B ON a.user_id=b.user_id;
```

json encode the data and send to client

and in your kendo grid change column user_id to name

Answer (score 0):

I know you were asking about the HTML/JavaScript way, but using MVC, this is a good, alternative way to do it:

http://decisivedata.net/kendo-ui-grid-and-entity-framework-code-first-foreign-key-fields/